# How is this problem categorised?

Tags: secondary-education, problem-solving

I'm trying to find some online questions and training material related to this sort of question. It's not something that I can identify the name of:

> A raffle has these prizes (ending 00 @ £12, ending 5 at £1.5), and tickets cost 50p. If all the winning tickets from 750 are sold (and some non-winning tickets), the total profit is £650. How many non-winning tickets were sold?

The solution goes along the lines of

1. calculate total winning tickets
2. calculate total prize money from #tickets
3. calculate total revenue
4. calculate total # tickets
5. subtract willing tickets
6. final answer.

I understand how to solve this specific problem, but is it a standard type of question, or just a one-off type of question? I'm hoping that there is a simple strategy for explaining this sort of question.

Comment: Is there any information missing from the sample question you posted? It would be helpful to see the entire thing. With the current information I would guess that this is a "solving a system of equations" type word problem.

Comment: Probably not any named category of problem. Just adding and multiplying (or rather, their inverses).

Comment: It's several stages, but I think I captured the essence. No one part is hard, just several steps.

Comment: I agree with Gareth, this sounds like a system of equations word problem but it's hard to tell for sure without seeing the entire thing.

Comment: So no clear source for similar questions to use for revision (UK GCSE in particular)?

Comment: I agree with Gareth Shepherd and tilper --- it's an [application of simultaneous linear equations problem at the high school level](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22simultaneous+linear+equations%22+applications+%22high%20school).

Comment: I am finding it slightly difficult to parse the actual question; e.g., I am not sure what "ending 00 @ £12, ending 5 at £1.5" means, and I think (but am not totally sure) that there are a few typos where "willing" has been typed instead of *winning*. Could you please clarify the question, and whether it is intended to supply sufficient information to find a unique answer?

Comment: @BenjaminDickman this is why I get so angry about exam boards setting english language tests in STEM papers. The question is not verbatim, I don't care about an answer to the question - just finding more similar questions (although the maths papers for this year are now mostly done).

Comment: @SeanHoulihane I mean that I literally do not understand the phrasing; of course, I cannot say anything substantive about "finding more similar questions" without grasping the original problem. I do not mean to be dense, pedantic, etc: But I do not understand the problem in its earlier or edited phrasing, and, therefore, I do not know how to solve it or how to address related questions.

Answer (score 2):

Answering the indirect question:

http://www.math-aids.com/ generates practice questions at a range of levels.

I haven't identified which (if any) sheets you want, but then I'm not entirely sure what you consider equivalent to the original question.

Comment: Close. 'Mixed operations with key phrases word problems' seems to show a simpler level of this sort of question. My example is effectively 3 linked questions of the form your link shows - where the intermediate stages need to be identified in order to answer the question.